# Unable to connect to MongoDB Atlas Cluster from Virtualbox

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I am trying to connect to my MongoDB Atlas Cluster from a Virtualbox running Windows10.

- Connecting from the computer running Virtualbox itself works fine.
- Internet connection in general works from Virtualbox (browsing, dropbox etc.)
- I am running the latest version of the shell on both computers - v4.0.10.
- I have added 0.0.0.0/0 to the white list as a means of troubleshooting it
  (it gives the same error).
- I have also added the shell executable to the firewall exceptions and separately opened for port 27017, both incoming and outgoing traffic on the Virtualbox.

Below is what is printed out in the terminal:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.379]
(c) 2018 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Windows\system32>mongo "mongodb+srv://cluster0-cd8gj.mongodb.net/test" --username xxxx
MongoDB shell version v4.0.10
Enter password:
connecting to: mongodb://cluster0-shard-00-00-cd8gj.mongodb.net.:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01-cd8gj.mongodb.net.:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02-cd8gj.mongodb.net.:27017/test?authSource=admin&gssapiServiceName=mongodb&replicaSet=Cluster0-shard-0&ssl=true
2019-07-18T17:58:13.929+0200 I NETWORK  [js] Starting new replica set monitor for Cluster0-shard-0/cluster0-shard-00-00-cd8gj.mongodb.net.:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01-cd8gj.mongodb.net.:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02-cd8gj.mongodb.net.:27017
2019-07-18T17:58:14.767+0200 W NETWORK  [js] Unable to reach primary for set Cluster0-shard-0
2019-07-18T17:58:14.796+0200 I NETWORK  [js] Cannot reach any nodes for set Cluster0-shard-0. Please check network connectivity and the status of the set. This has happened for 1 checks in a row.
2019-07-18T17:58:15.654+0200 W NETWORK  [js] Unable to reach primary for set Cluster0-shard-0
2019-07-18T17:58:15.654+0200 I NETWORK  [js] Cannot reach any nodes for set Cluster0-shard-0. Please check network connectivity and the status of the set. This has happened for 2 checks in a row.
2019-07-18T17:58:16.509+0200 W NETWORK  [js] Unable to reach primary for set Cluster0-shard-0
2019-07-18T17:58:16.510+0200 I NETWORK  [js] Cannot reach any nodes for set Cluster0-shard-0. Please check network connectivity and the status of the set. This has happened for 3 checks in a row.
2019-07-18T17:58:17.400+0200 W NETWORK  [js] Unable to reach primary for set Cluster0-shard-0
2019-07-18T17:58:17.519+0200 I NETWORK  [js] Cannot reach any nodes for set Cluster0-shard-0. Please check network connectivity and the status of the set. This has happened for 4 checks in a row.
2019-07-18T17:58:18.605+0200 W NETWORK  [js] Unable to reach primary for set Cluster0-shard-0
2019-07-18T17:58:18.672+0200 I NETWORK  [js] Cannot reach any nodes for set Cluster0-shard-0. Please check network connectivity and the status of the set. This has happened for 5 checks in a row.
2019-07-18T17:58:19.654+0200 W NETWORK  [js] Unable to reach primary for set Cluster0-shard-0
2019-07-18T17:58:19.655+0200 I NETWORK  [js] Cannot reach any nodes for set Cluster0-shard-0. Please check network connectivity and the status of the set. This has happened for 6 checks in a row.
2019-07-18T17:58:20.513+0200 W NETWORK  [js] Unable to reach primary for set Cluster0-shard-0
2019-07-18T17:58:20.514+0200 I NETWORK  [js] Cannot reach any nodes for set Cluster0-shard-0. Please check network connectivity and the status of the set. This has happened for 7 checks in a row.
2019-07-18T17:58:21.445+0200 W NETWORK  [js] Unable to reach primary for set Cluster0-shard-0
2019-07-18T17:58:21.496+0200 I NETWORK  [js] Cannot reach any nodes for set Cluster0-shard-0. Please check network connectivity and the status of the set. This has happened for 8 checks in a row.
2019-07-18T17:58:22.575+0200 W NETWORK  [js] Unable to reach primary for set Cluster0-shard-0
2019-07-18T17:58:22.576+0200 I NETWORK  [js] Cannot reach any nodes for set Cluster0-shard-0. Please check network connectivity and the status of the set. This has happened for 9 checks in a row.
2019-07-18T17:58:23.448+0200 W NETWORK  [js] Unable to reach primary for set Cluster0-shard-0
2019-07-18T17:58:23.457+0200 I NETWORK  [js] Cannot reach any nodes for set Cluster0-shard-0. Please check network connectivity and the status of the set. This has happened for 10 checks in a row.
2019-07-18T17:58:24.332+0200 W NETWORK  [js] Unable to reach primary for set Cluster0-shard-0
2019-07-18T17:58:24.348+0200 I NETWORK  [js] Cannot reach any nodes for set Cluster0-shard-0. Please check network connectivity and the status of the set. This has happened for 11 checks in a row.
2019-07-18T17:58:25.281+0200 W NETWORK  [js] Unable to reach primary for set Cluster0-shard-0
2019-07-18T17:58:26.206+0200 W NETWORK  [js] Unable to reach primary for set Cluster0-shard-0
2019-07-18T17:58:27.062+0200 W NETWORK  [js] Unable to reach primary for set Cluster0-shard-0
2019-07-18T17:58:27.926+0200 W NETWORK  [js] Unable to reach primary for set Cluster0-shard-0
2019-07-18T17:58:28.790+0200 W NETWORK  [js] Unable to reach primary for set Cluster0-shard-0


*** It looks like this is a MongoDB Atlas cluster. Please ensure that your IP whitelist allows connections from your network.


2019-07-18T17:58:28.988+0200 E QUERY    [js] Error: connect failed to replica set Cluster0-shard-0/cluster0-shard-00-00-cd8gj.mongodb.net.:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01-cd8gj.mongodb.net.:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02-cd8gj.mongodb.net.:27017 :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:344:17
@(connect):2:6
exception: connect failed
```

================================================

Any pointers in the right direction is greatly appreciated.

================================================

I can also add that I have set up a local MongoDB on the Virtualbox which is working.

Comment: Are you versions to the client and cluster up to date? Link:https://serverfault.com/questions/955555/unable-to-reach-primary-for-set-cluster0-shard-0

Comment: Yea, v4.0.10 is the latest version of the shell compatible with my cluster.

Comment: is the MongoDB service started? make sure you see it running in windows services. If not manually start it? Sorry it's hard to debug these errors.

Comment: Any help is appreciated. I am trying to connect to a remote cluster on mongodb.net. I don't have any service for mongodb running on the PC where the connection works.

Comment: What do you mean you don't have any service ? I apologize

Comment: I mean, on the PC where I am able to connect to the remote cluster, there is no service running that is related to MongoDB.